# mysql query sum based on years

Tags: database, mysql

i friend i have a database table

amount_id,
year,
amount,

and data like this

```
1 2002 2
2 2002 3
3 2007 2
4 2004 6
5 2004 10
```

i wan to run a query to select data like this

```
2002 4
2007 2
2004 16
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `year`, SUM(amount)
FROM databasetable
GROUP BY `year`
```

Should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use a sum(amount) in your select statement and group by year after your where.